# Pentaho localhost error

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to run the Pentaho BI Server and I keep getting the following error;

```
Pentaho Initialization Exception


The following errors were detected
One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml.
   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.BackingRepositoryLifecycleManagerSystemListener

Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.
```

I even tried rolling back to a older version of Java, but that wouldn't help
I'm a total newbie to Pentaho and any help to fix this would highly be appreciated

I'm following this guide to gmake the installations

```
http://cis.csuohio.edu/~sschung/cis611/DW_PentahoPivot4JInstallation.pdf
```

Thanks

Comment: Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.

Answer (score 0):

This guide

```
http://cis.csuohio.edu/~sschung/cis611/DW_PentahoPivot4JInstallation.pdf
```

you have mentioned have to be enchanted. It is not cover that to start successfully pentaho platform (you mention in as 'Pentaho BI Server') you  have to define [correct repository connection](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0F0/0P0/030).

The error

```
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.BackingRepositoryLifecycleManagerSystemListener
```

exactly says that platform cannot start since repository connection unavailable. The trick is when folks downloads CE edition of pentaho platform it comes with default configs that points to a postgres database with default credentials - admin/password. Assumed you already have locally installed postgres with user admin and grunted root access to this database. Otherwise - you have to edit repository, quarz connections manually and other stuff. This may be a [startpoint](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0F0). When you download and extract pentaho platform this is exactly manual installation case.

As opposite, EE version of pentaho uses binary installer, during this installation postgres installed automatically as far as correct users, access granted and configs is generated. When you had install pentaho platform this way you even may don't see that there is such functionality exists - just start using and have fun. From my experience CE edition require some tech background and following just Simon-says instructions sometimes is not enough.

And about java downgrade, Pentaho 7 release is compiled with java 8 and should be comfortable with that. For pre-7 pentaho releases you may use java 7.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error installing **5.0.1 BI server** on Windows 7 64 bit, the following worked for me - 
- **Do not use Java 8**, for some reason the Pentaho BI server and the JDK are not compatible. I went back to **Java 7**.
- Move the pentaho directory to be directly off the drive, as in c:\pentaho\biserver-ce... Apparently Tomcat has a problem with the long Windows paths. 
- make sure you set your **JAVA_HOME**, etc.

Comment: Could you explain how to uninstall/install java and `java_home` path?. Thanks

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml